# How to select the Data Source at Runtime in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

I need to dynamically specify the data source for SSRS reports at runtime. I found these solutions:

[Dynamically set the data source for SSRS reports without unattended execution account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065148/dynamically-set-the-data-source-for-ssrs-reports-without-unattended-execution-ac)

[How to select the Data Source at Runtime in SSRS Report Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847081/how-to-select-the-data-source-at-runtime-in-ssrs-report-builder)

After reading these solution I have implemented like below:

1. Created RDL file with two report parameters ServerName & DatabaseName
2. Create Embedded Datasource
3. While embedded connection, Set connection string with formula like below:

   `="data source=" & Parameters!ServerName.Value & ";initial catalog=" & Parameters!DatabaseName.Value & ";Integrated Security=SSPI;"`
4. While embedded connection, Credential option need to select “Do not use credentials”
5. Define execution account in reporting service configuration

With above steps I have achieved data source at runtime in SSRS. But it will work only if databases are in same machine where reporting service installed.

In my case, Reporting Service is installed on Azure VM & database which I am pointing its on Azure Database Service. So obviously windows authentication will not work.

Any one have solution? please share...!!

Thanks